# How to check for Duplicate strings on an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm kind of new to java and I'm trying to make a guessing game that looks for User01's duplicate. I'm encountering a problem and I have no idea how do I fix this. My goal is to check if User01 has already entered that specific word. Here is my code as of right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    int k = x;
    boolean Given = false;
    boolean Given2 = false;
//Playerone and x are in Global Declarations.
    for(int j = 0; j < x; j++, k--){
        if(j == 0){
            System.out.print("Please enter " + k + " words that Player 2 will Guess:");
            Playerone[j] = input.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        else if(j == x-1){
            System.out.print("Last one:");
            Playerone[j] = input.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        else {
        System.out.print(k + " more words:");
        Playerone[j] = input.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println(j);
        }
        do {
        int Duplicates = 0;
        while(Duplicates > j && Playerone[Duplicates] == Playerone[j]){
          Duplicates++;
        }
        Given2= Duplicates < j;
            if(Given2 == false){
                Given2 = true; 
                System.out.println("It's already given");
                Playerone[j] = input.nextLine();
            }
        }while(Given2 = true);
}
```

I tried placing do below the start of for-loop, and it doesn't fixed the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the condition:

```
Duplicates>j
```

which is always false and doesn’t allow `Duplicates++`
also `Duplicates=0;` Happens every time User1 gives a word so this will never work to count Duplicates anyway.

Fist of all move `Duplicates=0;` before the fist for loop

So what I would instead of the last do...while is :

```
Given=false;
for(int c=0;c<=j;c++){
     while(Playerone[j]==Playerone[c])
      //duplicate found 
      System.out.println(“Already exists”);
       Playerone[j]=input.nextLine();
       Given=true;
        }
    //these loop also prevent user to give again a word that already exists 
}
if(Given) Duplicates++;
```